# Difference between () and = in C++

Tags: c++, class, static, constexpr

When I initialize a variable, I usually use "()".

```
int myVariable(5);
```

This used to work all the time but the following throws a compilation error!

```
struct Database
{
public:
    Database();
    ~Database();
    static constexpr uint8_t variable(10); // ERROR!
    static constexpr uint8_t variable2 = 10; // Fine
};
```

Apparently, I cannot use the parenthesis here but the "=" works fine! Why is that?

Errors from the compiler: "expected identifier before numeric constant" and
"expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant".

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is "because the C++ grammar is made that way". You can use `{}` though.

Comment: _"Why is that?"_ Because the correct syntax for in declaration initialization demands it.

Comment: I had not seen the other topic! Alright noted, thanks!